# How to convert this Root expression in to a normal algebraic form?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I need to convert this root expression in to a normal form
`-(RootSum[1 + y #1 + Sqrt[y] #1^2 + y^(1/3) #1^3 &,  Log[-#1]/(y^(2/3) + 2 y^(1/6) #1 + 3 #1^2) &]/y^(1/3))`

I tried this `-(RootSum[1 + y #1 + Sqrt[y] #1^2 + y^(1/3) #1^3 &,  Log[-#1]/(y^(2/3) + 2 y^(1/6) #1 + 3 #1^2) &]/y^(1/3))//Normal//ToRadicals//FullSimplify`

but not getting any result.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you remove FullSimplify from your attempt, you get the required form.

Comment: "ToRadicals" vonverts Root object to radicals.

Comment: The `Normal` is not necessary. For your `expr`: `(expr // Normal // ToRadicals) === (expr // ToRadicals)` evaluates to `True`